# Connect a microSD reader to a LilyPad USB, where are the digital ports?

Tags: arduino, sd, pinout, lilypad

I am attempting to connect a [microSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Physical_size) breakout board to a [LilyPad Arduino USB](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardLilyPadUSB).
The microSD board has previously been connected to an [Arduino Duemilanove](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardDuemilanove).

In the Duemilanove setup, the following connections were made successfully:

(SD) -> Duemilanove

- (CS) -> Pin 10 (SS)
- (DI) -> Pin 11 (MOSI)
- (DO) -> Pin 12 (MISO)
- (CLK) -> Pin 13 (SCK)

Plus 5 V and ground.

I have attempted to replicate this with the LilyPad USB, following [the schematic](http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-lilypad-usb-schematic.pdf).

(SD) -> LilyPad USB

- (CS) -> Pin D17 (SS)
- (DI) -> Pin D16 (MOSI)
- (DO) -> Pin D14 (MISO)
- (CLK) -> Pin D15 (SCK)

However, the problem is, I cannot locate this digital pins physically on the LilyPad USB. I believe they are the six pins in a rectangle formation next to analogue port A2, but I do not know which are which. Following the forum post *[LilyPad USB v1.1 and SPI](https://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=35439)*, I have tried that combination, but I have not had any results.

What is the order of the six pins? Also, where is the SS pin (that doesn't seem to be included there)?

Answer (score 1):

The programming header will have MISO, MOSI and SCK. Use a multimeter to check continuity from the header to the Atmega32u4 pins.

The mapping between Atmega32u4 and Arduino pin numbers is [here](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping32u4). I don't see a digital pin 17 in the mapping, so use a digital pin which exists and change the library. The [schematic](http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-lilypad-usb-schematic.pdf) shows A2, A3, A4, A5, D2, D3, D9, D10 and D11 as the 9 IO pins on the exterior of the pcb, or you could bodge wire directly to another pin of the MCU.

Comment: Thank you, this has worked, I used D2 as the CS pin. Maybe I will connect it to the MCU in the future, but for now this works.

Answer (score 0):

You were right with the pinout.

I've looked at the [Eagle files](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/E-Textiles/Lilypad/Lilypad_32u4_v10.zip) of Lilypad PCB and the image that has in the forum its right, the pinout its like this:

[image]

All the pins are correct and really connected at the MCU. Maybe have some problem in the program, some port definition, or something like this.